Jacod and Protters Proof of characteristic uniqueness of functions, extending from compact to infinity.
I want to fill in the details in Jacod and Protter's proof of the uniqueness of characteristic functions. The problem is that we have something that works for a compact set, and I want it to work for all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I highlighted what I want to fill in the details for:

Attempt at filling in the details:
From what I see, the stone Weierstrass theorem only works for compact spaces. So what I understand this is what we got:
Assume that $f$ is a function vanishing at infinity ($f \in \mathcal{C}_0$). For every $k\in 
\mathbb{N}$ we have that there exists $h_k  \in \mathcal{H}$ such that for every $\lvert x \rvert <k$ we have
$$|f(x)-h_k(x)|<\frac{1}{k}.$$
We now get:
$$\left \lvert\int f d\mu_1-\int f d\mu_2 \right \rvert\le \int \lvert f -h_k\rvert d\mu_1+\left \lvert\int h_k d\mu_1-\int h_k d\mu_2\right \rvert+\int \lvert h_k -f\rvert d\mu_2$$
The second part is zero by what is done earlier in the proof. The first and third integrals behave similarly because of symmetry, so let's focus on $\int \lvert f -h_k\rvert d\mu_1$. We get
$$\int \lvert f -h_k\rvert d\mu_1=\int\limits_{\vert x \rvert<k} \lvert f -h_k\rvert d\mu_1+\int\limits_{\vert x \rvert\ge k} \lvert f -h_k\rvert d\mu_1$$.
The first integral is less than $1/k$. So we are left with $\int\limits_{\vert x \rvert\ge k} \lvert f -h_k\rvert d\mu_1$.
What I know is that $f$ vanishes as it goes to infinity, that I have not used yet. I also know that $h_k$ vanishes as $x$ goes to infinity for fixed $k$. However, the problem is this: I can bound $|f|<\epsilon$ as $x\ge K$ for some $K$ for any $\epsilon>0$. The problem is that I can not bound $h_k$ for $\lvert x \rvert \ge K$. I know that each $h_k$ goes to zero as $k$ becomes large, because of the $e^{-\lvert x\rvert ^2}$-part, but I am not able to uniformly bound them.
Do you know how to solve this?
Update:
One thing that I see will solve this is if I can uniformly bound all the $h_k$'s by a constant.
PS: The book is online here
It is on page 111.

I found out that I needed the locally compact version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, not just the compact version:

Let X be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $C_0(X)$ denote the
Banach space of continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that
vanish at $\infty$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a sub-algebra of $C_0(X)$
such that
a) $x \ne y \rightarrow f(x)\ne f(y)$ for some $f \in \mathcal{A}$
b) $x \in X \rightarrow f(x) \ne 0$ for some $f \in \mathcal{A}$
Then $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $ C_0(X)$.

https://statmathbc.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/stonewei.pdf
The statement(but not proof) is also on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem
